# How do I upload an image from a URL to Firebase Storage?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am using Node.JS.
I can't seem to figure it out. I've updated the modules.
Old code:

```
var mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
var randomString = uuidv4();
var options = {
    destination: 'test',
    metadata: { 
        contentType: mimeType,
        metadata: {
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: randomString
        }
    }
};
return admin.storage().bucket().upload(userPhotoDownloadLink, options).then(()=>{
    //
}).catch((err) => {
    print(`Error Uploading Image:${err}`);
    //
});
```

This code no longer works. How do I upload via an http link. Google Cloud 2.4.x only shows guides on local file uploads.

EDIT:

```
var uploadPhoto = async function(public_courier_id,userPhotoDownloadLink){
var mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
var randomString = "testkey123";
var options = {
    //destination: 'courierPhotos/' + public_courier_id,
    metadata: { 
        contentType: mimeType,
        metadata: {
            firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: randomString
        }
    }
};
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(`courierPhotos/${public_courier_id}`)
console.log(`Fetching File...`);
return fetch(userPhotoDownloadLink).then(res=>{
    console.log(`Successfully Fetched, Piping File...`)
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        res.body.pipe(file.createWriteStream(options))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            reject(`err: ${err}`)
        })
        .on('finish', function() {
            resolve(`complete`);
        });
    })
});
}

return uploadPhoto("TESTUID","https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
.then(res => console.log(`Printing after function ${res}`))
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Use an HTTP library to download the content from the URL, then pipe it to Cloud Storage.  The Firebase/Cloud SDK will not do this automatically.

Comment: @DougStevenson Just edited it, please let me know if that's what you meant. And if I'm handling it correctly with Promises and what not. Im new to piping. Thanks!